In the project I developed in Android Studio, the wifi direct system detects the device but cannot send data
I am working on a project in Android studio where I use wifi direct but even if it finds the devices connected to the wifi network, it cannot send data. I haven't been able to solve the problem for weeks, I want to write it cleanly from scratch, can you help me with this? Are there any sources I can get examples from?
I am working on an application that sends photos between phones using WiFi Direct, but I cannot send the photos even though it finds devices connected to WiFi in the WiFi Direct section.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I dont have code an mi right now but ı can send in a couple hours. I want example to edit. Can you provide?
